# simple AJAX for passing jquery's datepicker variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Im beginner in JS & AJAX so please bear with me.

I use codeigniter framework in this project. I want to create a datepicker and passing its value through AJAX. This is the script :

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
        });

        $("#btn_insert").click(function() {
            var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>" + "index.php/backend/umat";

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: $('#my_form').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    /*var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);*/
                    alert("a");
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

The datepicker is already shown & working fine. However the AJAX is still not working. When i tried to alert the error (the one i commented in code), it doesnt alert anything. So i tried to `alert("a");` and yes, `"a"` is alerted so theres something wrong in the AJAX. The data is never alerted which means it never success.

Theres no error in the console. Im using chrome browser.

Any help is appreciated and please just ask me if you need something. Thanks :D

Comment: if your using the chrome browser please use the developer tools in it, especially the network tab will give you all the information you need

Comment: try `console.log(url)` just before you call `$.ajax()`, the url is likely to be malformed... and don't use that `eval` call. I know you've commented it out, but just delete it. It's no good to you here

Comment: Try calling console.log(status) your error hook. Possible values can be (besides null) "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try writing this url in you browser http://mysite.com/index.php/backend/umat and show information? check your htaccess perhaps index.php is delete